# pandas plot CDF for multi-class column

Tags: python, pandas, cdf

I am working with the python [empyrical-dist](https://pypi.org/project/empyrical-dist/) package to plot a `CDF` of speed distribution with respect to traval mode (multi-class).

```
data.head()
+---+---------+----------+----------+-------+--------------+------------+
|   | trip_id | distance | duration | speed | acceleration | travelmode |
+---+---------+----------+----------+-------+--------------+------------+
| 0 |  303637 | 5.92     | 0.51     | 3.20  | 0.00173      | metro      |
| 1 |  303638 | 3.54     | 0.22     | 4.44  | 0.00557      | bus        |
| 2 |  303642 | 4.96     | 0.20     | 6.84  | 0.00944      | car        |
| 3 |  303662 | 6.53     | 0.97     | 1.86  | 0.00053      | foot       |
| 4 |  303663 | 40.23    | 0.94     | 11.85 | 0.00349      | car        |
+---+---------+----------+----------+-------+--------------+------------+
```

now what to plot the `CDF` of `speed` column for each mode in `travelmode`. So,

```
from empiricaldist import Cdf

def decorate_cdf(title, x, y):
    """Labels the axes.

    title: string
    """
    plt.xlabel(x)
    plt.ylabel(y)
    plt.title(title)

for name, group in data.groupby('travelmode'):
    Cdf.from_seq(group.speed).plot()

title, x, y = 'Speed by mode','speed (km/h)', 'CDF'
decorate_cdf(title,x,y)
```

[image]

How do I then add legend to each plot so I can tell which plot is for what mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use matplotlib's [`pyplot.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) command:

```
plt.legend(data.groupby('travelmode').groups.keys())
```

Comment: Could you please shade more light to your answer?

Comment: If you add `plt.legend(data.groupby('travelmode').groups.keys())` to your `decorate_cdf(title, x, y)` function, you should get a legend with the group names so you know which plot if for what mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the argument "label = " to the plot method associated with Cdf, like this:

```
Cdf.from_seq(group.speed).plot(label = 'metro')
```

or pass a list in your case instead of 'metro'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When including code in a question, answer, or comment, you should use backticks (` `) or code blocks to format it so it is easier to read. See more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help